# Different types of seal lead acid (SLA) battery chargers!

Tags: batteries, battery-charging

I'm new here and want advice on battery chargers to buy for my 12v 18AH/20HR sla battery! I want to know if a 6v and 12v 1200 mAh battery charger could charge this battery and how long would I have to charge it for?! The charger does not have any light source indicating if it's on or off or when the battery if full either, is this good charger to buy?! [image: The black charger is a Nippon America 6v/12v 1200 MA and the other just as it's labelled a 6v/12v 8Ah, which charger is better to charge both a 6v 2.8Ah and a 12v 18Ah both cost $150 ttd][image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you get a good battery charger with proper indicator and battery full auto cut-off feature. Plus your battery is quite big and you will need to charge it around 0.2C to 0.3C. The former is better for battery longevity.

Get a good automotive battery charger that can charge upto 8A. If you are short of cash, search ebay or your local junkyard and you might find those old manual car battery chargers (with slow and fast) like from Schumacher or Bosch. But with these you have to be careful to keep watch on the amp gauge and prevent from overcharging.

Also these have the ability to revive batteries with very low voltage(over-discharged) below 9V compared to modern automatic chargers.

Comment: Would a 6v/12v 8Ah charger be ok to use for this battery?!  Thanks!

Comment: @Ronell There are a few things you might want to consider before buying these cheap chargers.

Comment: First, from the first picture its too weak for the battery of your size will take almost ages to charge. The second ones seem to be fine but let me warn you they are far worse than those old manual chargers. Well if you plan to use it to charge a cheap battery or for emergency purpose its okay. You need to make sure to get a charger that can out put around 3-4Amps of current of charge a 20Ah battery else charging process could take days to complete. If you use an SLA type then get a good quality one.

Comment: for flooded ones you can compensate for the water loss due to overcharge by refilling but for an SLA you cannot. So, just keep that in mind while you buy. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your reply and infomation! What does the 8ah means in the second charger, 8 amps or 8 amp-hrs?! Isn't 8 amps the same as 8000 mah

Comment: The Ah rating on a battery typically means  for example in your case a 20Ah battery can be used at 20A for 1 hour before its discharged. Using it at 40A will give you a 30 mins run time. The one battery charger might be confusing sometimes. It could probably mean the charger is best for an 8Ah Lead acid battery? Maybe someone here could confirm that for you. Usually lead acid batteries are charged at 10 to 30% of the battery capacity. Eg charging a 20Ah from 2A minimum to 6A max. Get a cheap 8A automotive amp gauge or use a multi-meter amp (10A setting) to keep an eye on you current.

Comment: What is the max current that the above charger can provide(I assume it could be around 0.8 to 2.5A not sure)? For extending life of your battery I recommend getting a 3 stage smart charger.

Comment: thank you very much for your time and knowledge, much appreciated!!